# Split a string into only 3 characters. Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, split

I need to take a string of so many characters and make it to only 3. For example, if I have read in a string "November" I want to convert it to "Nov". I was wondering what the operation would be to do this if:

```
       String month = "November";
       //I want month = "Nov"
```

I have to do this for many different months. I tried using the .replace() but I could not figure out the correct regexp to get it to delete everything after the third character.

Comment: Remember that `substring(0,3)` will throw an exception for strings of only 2 characters in length ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need regex for this task.  If the length of `month` is more than 3, then call the [`substring` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).  It takes two parameters -- one for the beginning position of the substring (inclusive), and one for the ending position of the substring (exclusive).  Indices are 0-based.

Comment: Thank you, new to Java, I knew there was some method to cut it down, just didn't know what it was quite yet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

```
String month = "November";

month = month.substring(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
month.substring(0, 3);
```

For details see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)